# Enable JSTL support once and for all JSP pages (not on "per-every-single-page" basis)

Tags: java, jsp, jstl

In order to enable JSTL support in all my JSP pages I need to insert `<%@ taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" prefix="c"%>` tag in each one of them.

Is it possible to write some declaration once so that every JSP page in my project has jstl enabled by default?

I can create a template of a JSP page but I need to enable jstl support for many JSP pages previously created (then I will edit them).

Comment: I am not aware of any such directive, but inserting a line into multiple text files is simple (in *nix based system), see https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/1197/adding-a-line-of-text-to-multiple-files

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't, you have to declare the library `<%@ taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" prefix="c"%>` on each page, there isn't any magic configuration file which can achieve this for you. However, you can make the insert of this row in your `JSP` easier.